# Determining Pandas Column DataType

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sometimes when data is imported to Pandas Dataframe, it always imports as type `object`.  This is fine and well for doing most operations, but I am trying to create a custom export function, and my question is this:

- Is there a way to force Pandas to infer the data types of the input data?
- If not, is there a way after the data is loaded to infer the data types somehow?

I know I can tell Pandas that this is of type int, str, etc.. but I don't want to do that, I was hoping pandas could be smart enough to know all the data types when a user imports or adds a column.

EDIT - example of import

```
a = ['a']
col = ['somename']
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=col)
print(df.dtypes)
>>> somename    object
dtype: object
```

The type should be string?

Comment: Can you explain how you are importing the data, `read_csv` for instance will sniff the dtypes whilst `read_excel` uses the excel dtypes

Comment: Sure, I expect users to be using all the various import methods

Comment: Here `object` is `np.object` which is the correct type for strings, also this is not importing, it's creation

Comment: If you do `type(df['somename'].iloc[0])` you will see that it is a `str`

Comment: So if you look at the rows, you can get the types.  Is there a way to get the majority data type for each column?  Let's say I expand the rows and one contains a NULL and 5 string values, the column would then be of type string... or maybe filter out NULL values then do the majority value?

Comment: mixed dtypes will become `object`, there is no `NaN` type for non numeric types

Comment: @EdChum - so I am doing a variation to handle a case where NULL maybe in a column.  ```t = df[col].loc[df[col].notnull()]```... It works well except when I go to do t[0], I get an index error.  How can I do this so the t[0] always works if the first row do have a null value in that column?

Comment: I recently wrote the following for a similar issue: `[df.iloc[:,i].apply(type).value_counts() for i in range(df.shape[1])]` This will print out "frequency tables" of data type for each variable in a DataFrame.

Comment: @lmo, can you post that solution as an answer with an expanded example?

Comment: It is not so much an answer to your question as a diagnostic.

Comment: That's basically what I need, just wanted to see how you applied it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is only a partial answer, but you can get frequency counts of the data type of the elements in a variable over the entire DataFrame as follows:

```
dtypeCount =[df.iloc[:,i].apply(type).value_counts() for i in range(df.shape[1])]
```

This returns

```
dtypeCount

[<class 'numpy.int32'>    4
 Name: a, dtype: int64,
 <class 'int'>    2
 <class 'str'>    2
 Name: b, dtype: int64,
 <class 'numpy.int32'>    4
 Name: c, dtype: int64]
```

It doesn't print this nicely, but you can pull out information for any variable by location:

```
dtypeCount[1]

<class 'int'>    2
<class 'str'>    2
Name: b, dtype: int64
```

which should get you started in finding what data types are causing the issue and how many of them there are.

You can then inspect the rows that have a str object in the second variable using

```
df[df.iloc[:,1].map(lambda x: type(x) == str)]

   a  b  c
1  1  n  4
3  3  g  6
```

**data**

```
df = DataFrame({'a': range(4),
                'b': [6, 'n', 7, 'g'],
                'c': range(3, 7)})
```

Comment: I just wrapped 'dtypeCount' into a dataframe and it looks beautiful... :D 
pandas.DataFrame(dtypeCount)

Answer (score 3):

You can also infer the objects from after dropping irrelevant items by using `infer_objects()`. Below is a general example.

```
df_orig = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", 1, 2, 3], "B": ["b", 1.2, 1.8, 1.8]})
df = df_orig.iloc[1:].infer_objects()
print(df_orig.dtypes, df.dtypes, sep='\n\n')
```

Output:

[image: output print]

Answer (score 2):

Here an (not perfect) try to write an better inferer. When you have allready data in your dataframe, the inferer will guess the smallet type possible. Datetime is currently missing, but I think it could be an starting point. With this inferer, i can get down 70% of the memory in use.

```
def infer_df(df, hard_mode=False, float_to_int=False, mf=None):
    ret = {}

    # ToDo: How much does auto convertion cost
    # set multiplication factor
    mf = 1 if hard_mode else 0.5

    # set supported datatyp
    integers = ['int8', 'int16', 'int32', 'int64']
    floats = ['float16', 'float32', 'float64']

    # ToDo: Unsigned Integer

    # generate borders for each datatype
    b_integers = [(np.iinfo(i).min, np.iinfo(i).max, i) for i in integers]
    b_floats = [(np.finfo(f).min, np.finfo(f).max, f) for f in floats]

    for c in df.columns:
        _type = df[c].dtype

        # if a column is set to float, but could be int
        if float_to_int and np.issubdtype(_type, np.floating):
            if np.sum(np.remainder(df[c], 1)) == 0:
                df[c] = df[c].astype('int64')
                _type = df[c].dtype

        # convert type of column to smallest possible
        if np.issubdtype(_type, np.integer) or np.issubdtype(_type, np.floating):
            borders = b_integers if np.issubdtype(_type, np.integer) else b_floats

            _min = df[c].min()
            _max = df[c].max()

            for b in borders:
                if b[0] * mf < _min and _max < b[1] * mf:
                    ret[c] = b[2]
                    break

        if _type == 'object' and len(df[c].unique()) / len(df) < 0.1:
            ret[c] = 'category'

    return ret
```

Comment: Good job to write your own df.infer_objects()! Do you have new version of it?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry but I'm not pleased by df.infer_objects()...

Comment: @MinsterMonk I think your self-define function may help others about reducing memory usage `automatically`. Why you are not pleased by `df.infer_objects`?

Comment: It was long ago but df.infer_objects() sets the boundaries to wide. If you have a completed dataset where you don't add data you want that so small as possible. Also with modifications there will be conversion in pandas automaticly. I will try to provide an example on github and make an comparison.