# how do i get the datatype of eachvalue in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, types

I have dataframe df with following value:

```
0                                    abcc
1                                      11
2                                    TRUE
3                                 "123.5"
4                            192.168.1.55
5                   "123.4555, 123.53422"
6                              12/23/1999
7                                      AF
8                        9° 3' 33.228'' N
9                      9° 47' 20.6268'' W
10  "8° 3' 33.228'' N,8° 47' 20.6268'' W"
11                             1582088645
```

I transposed the data frame and checked the dtypes are shown for sequence number of axis:

```
data=data.transpose()
    for i, j in data.dtypes.iteritems():
        print(i,j)
 0 object
 1 object
 .
 .
 .
 11 object
```

How to skip this sequence number . so i can achive dtype of each value?
     I want something like this

```
abcc object
10 int64
TRUE bool
“123.5” object
192.168.1.54 object
“123.4555, 123.53422” object
12/23/1998 object
AF object
8° 3' 33.228'' N object
8° 47' 20.6268'' W object
“8° 3' 33.228'' N,8° 47' 20.6268'' W” object
1582088644 int64
```

Comment: Just do this: `data.dtypes`
Will return all column names with dtypes

Comment: @RaghulRaj He has used data.dtypes only.

Comment: data.dtypes dosent work it gives me the dtype of indices

Comment: Your initial dataframe (before the transpose) `data` contains only one column. So pandas has converted all the values to `object`. Take a look at [Essential Basic Functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#basics-dtypes) to set  `data types` for indiviudal columns

Comment: does this helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/49926897/6660373

Comment: @DOOM i am reading list and constructing a dataframe which has no headers, since i am unaware of what the list will be i cant set the data types, even before transposing

Comment: @Pygirl it converts everything to string! so i cant get dtype of dataframe

Comment: If I am correct pandas can't have mixed data type in a column. If there is int, boolean then they will be treated as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit unconventional but gives you, what you want:

```
df =pd.DataFrame(data=["abcc", 11, "TRUE", "123.5", "192.168.1.55", "123.4555, 123.53422",
                       "12/23/1999","AF","9° 3' 33.228'' N", "9° 47' 20.6268'' W", 
                       "8° 3' 33.228'' N,8° 47' 20.6268'' W", 1582088645])
for col, dtype in zip(df.T.values[0],df.T.dtypes):
    print(col, dtype)
```

Output is:

```
abcc object
11 object
TRUE object
123.5 object
192.168.1.55 object
123.4555, 123.53422 object
12/23/1999 object
AF object
9° 3' 33.228'' N object
9° 47' 20.6268'' W object
8° 3' 33.228'' N,8° 47' 20.6268'' W object
1582088645 object
```

You have to be careful, because this will work only with the data you provided

Comment: Every dtype of value is given as object in this case. so it didnt work

Comment: Sorry, but you cannot define pandas dataframe column with mixed types. The answer is exactly, what you asked for.

Comment: Ya i know that . so i converted column into rows by doing transpose in the first place

Comment: And this gives again for `1582088645 - dtype object ` , as you can see from your post