# How to know the content of a Pandas dataframe column if the data type is object

Tags: pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe with a column whose dtype is `object`, and when I print the dataframe content, the column show the value `True`, but I can't tell if such value is a boolean or a string (both are possible).

How can I find it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I know the type of a pandas dataframe cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926897/how-can-i-know-the-type-of-a-pandas-dataframe-cell)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it all printed out you could just check the exact type of teach element by applying `type` function with `map` or `apply`

```py
x = pd.DataFrame([True, 'True', 0, False])
x[0].map(type)
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know: [How can I know the type of a pandas dataframe cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49926897/12846804)

Different type, but still a duplicate?

For example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'numeric' : [1, 1., 2, 3],
                   'objects' : [1, True, 'True', False]})
df
   numeric objects
0      1.0       1
1      1.0    True
2      2.0    True
3      3.0   False

df.applymap(type)
           numeric         objects
0  <class 'float'>   <class 'int'>
1  <class 'float'>  <class 'bool'>
2  <class 'float'>   <class 'str'>
3  <class 'float'>  <class 'bool'>
```

*<class 'bool'>* vs *<class 'str'>*:

- map (for a series),
- applymap (for a dataframe)

... will allow you to cast the type function by cells instead of getting the column *dtype*.

Comment: This is a duplicate as far as I'm concerned. Particular types don't make a difference in that respect, otherwise we could have questions asking, "How do I know if this is a list?", "How do I know if this is a datetime?", etc.

Comment: I have just noticed that applymap is [Deprecated since version 2.1.0: DataFrame.applymap has been deprecated. Use DataFrame.map instead.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html).
Should try the recommended alternative.