# Fastest way to find all data types in a pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, types

What is the fastest way to show all value types in a pandas series?

I know that I can just do the `df.dtypes`, but if a column has both `string` and `int`, it just returns `object`, which is not particularly helpful.

Currently I am stuck with:

```
set(type(x) for x in df['column'])
```

However I got tired of writing this every time, so I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: If you have no information about your data, it seems to me that that would be the fastest way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41262370/determining-pandas-column-datatype

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use `apply(type)`:

```
s = pd.Series(['1', 2, 3, '4'])

print(s)

0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
dtype: object
```

Apply type:

```
s.apply(type)

0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'str'>
dtype: object
```

---

To get the unique values:

```
s.apply(type).unique()

array([<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>], dtype=object)
```

---

To get a more cleaner list:

```
[x for x in s.apply(type).unique()]

[str, int]
```

Comment: Can also do `s.apply(type).value_counts()`, which will show the count of each type in the series.

Comment: @Erfan the first option is faster in writing, but the later one is pretty much the same